# LibGDX: Importing a newly generated project fails (Eclipse)

Tags: java, eclipse, gradle, libgdx

This is my project setup:

[image: LibGDX Project Setup]

Generating the project worked fine. After that I tried to import it into the Eclipse IDE.
The generated project is a Gradle project, so I did the following: File -> Import -> Gradle -> Existing Gradle Project. I selected the folder "Jagario-Game", kept the default eclipse Gradle settings (uses gradle wrapper version 6.7) and clicked "Finish". The console shows following:

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL in 272ms
> Task :nothing UP-TO-DATE

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 403ms
Working Directory: F:\harry\Documents\Informatik\Jagario-Game
Gradle user home: C:\Users\harry\.gradle
Gradle Distribution: Gradle wrapper from target build
Gradle Version: 6.7
Java Home: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-14.0.1
JVM Arguments: None
Program Arguments: None
Build Scans Enabled: false
Offline Mode Enabled: false
> Task :html:cleanEclipseWtpComponent
> Task :html:cleanEclipseWtpFacet
> Task :html:cleanEclipseWtp UP-TO-DATE
> Task :html:eclipseWtpComponent
> Task :html:eclipseWtpFacet
> Task :html:eclipseWtp

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

BUILD SUCCESSFUL in 333ms
5 actionable tasks: 4 executed, 1 up-to-date

Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings

CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL in 251ms
```

Even though there are a lot of "BUILD SUCCESSFUL" and "CONFIGURE SUCCESSFUL" messages, the following message seems to be a problem:

```
Deprecated Gradle features were used in this build, making it incompatible with Gradle 7.0.
Use '--warning-mode all' to show the individual deprecation warnings.
See https://docs.gradle.org/6.7/userguide/command_line_interface.html#sec:command_line_warnings
```

Added to that my project doesn't get build (all modules are missing!):

[image]

I don't know much about Gradle so I'm not sure how to get this error fixed. Am I using the wrong gradle version? Or is this an eclipse bug?

Comment: This warning is not a problem. Gradle 7.0 introduce new feature and remove others.
Your build use old feature. But because you not use Gradle 7.0 your build will be succesful. If you don't use gradle much don't worry for the moment. 
You can take a look to https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/upgrading_version_6.html to upgrade but this is not necessary

Comment: But all modules (core and desktop-project) are "missing". I have no way to edit the source-code or compile my game within eclipse.

Comment: I'm not an expert in eclipse (i'm using intellij) 
But try to go into your project with a cli and use commande `./gradlew build`
If the build is successful the problem come from eclipse configuration. 
(Successful with core and desktop task ex core:build)